# Optimizar una consulta MySQL que pone al servidor al 100% de CPU

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta que hace que el servidor MariaDB ocupe un 100% de CPU durante más de 10 minutos y finalmente la página da timeout.

La consulta en cuestión es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
  formasdepago.nombre as 'Forma de pago', 
  SUM(transaccion) AS Total 
FROM contabilidad 
INNER JOIN formasdepago ON formasdepago.id = contabilidad.formadepago 
WHERE contabilidad.anulado = 0  
Group By formadepago
```

Las tablas correspondientes son las siguientes:

**Contabilidad**:

```
CREATE TABLE `contabilidad` (
    `anulado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cuentacorriente` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cuotas` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `empleado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `formadepago` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idgasto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `interesfinanciero` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `interesformadepago` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ticketid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tipodetransaccion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `transaccion` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `valordecuota` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `valorfinal` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`),
    INDEX `ticketid` (`ticketid`),
    INDEX `idgasto` (`idgasto`),
    INDEX `formadepago` (`formadepago`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `tipodetransaccion` (`tipodetransaccion`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=13975947
;
```

**Forma de pago**:

```
CREATE TABLE `formasdepago` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `habilitado` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `eliminado` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `simbolo` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `diferencia` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `imagen` MEDIUMBLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `preciodelista` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `numeropreciodelista` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `financiacion` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `imagenmini` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `eliminado` (`eliminado`),
    INDEX `habilitado` (`habilitado`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8
;
```

Contabilidad tiene 1,5 GB de información, mientras que forma de pago solo lleva 3 registros.

Con semejante cantidad de datos, los separo por fecha para realizar una consulta más pequeña, pero no entiendo por qué es la demora.

¿Alguien podría darme algún indicio del qué está haciendo el servidor para que tarde tanto? No lo entiendo la verdad. Espero que alguien me ayude, muchas gracias.

Comment: A ver, ¿puedes explicar el sentido de esto: `FULLTEXT INDEX tipodetransaccion (tipodetransaccion)`  y de esto: `FULLTEXT INDEX nombre (nombre)`? ¿Sabes para qué sirven los índices `FULLTEXT`?

Comment: podrías hacer el sum where y group by en un subquery y luego hacer el join?

Comment: Es probable que el groupBy ralentice más de lo normal la consulta, si tienes la certeza de que son solo tres formas de pago, podrías realizar una query para cada uno y luego un union para juntarlas.

Comment: creo que lo he colocado mal a eso, estaba probando fulltext index, pues algunas transacciones son "Pago" otras "Debe" entonces, lo que ahgo es indexarlo para buscar mas rapido, y malbarez, un subquery supongo yo, seria mas lento :S

Comment: habría que ver cómo lo interpreta el optimizador, pero me da la sensación de que al hacer un subquery la cantidad de datos en memoria es menor , menos campos, y luego el join sobre este subset (formadepago, total) tambíen sería mas rápido.

Comment: alguien podria formularme una respuesta por favor, porque no se me ocurre la idea que me estan pasando, o proponiendo, muchas gracias

Comment: te armé un fiddle para que veas los diferentes execution plan que tira mySQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/161fab/1 y cómo varía con un subquery, tendrías que probar con tu dataset y en MariaDB para ver si el uso de index en la subquery es mas rápido (click en view execution plan)

Comment: Agarre lo que hizo @aloMalbarez y le agregue otro query mas http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/161fab/3. Imposible poenr una respuesta, pueden ser tantas cosas que sin tener datos no es facil saber que pasa. Fijate el ultimo query, que lo ultimo que hace es joinear.. y no joinea, si no que va y busca los datos a mano.

Comment: Prueba la performance quitando el filtro `contabilidad.anulado = 0` y nos cuentas.

Comment: Quitando anulado=0 da el mismo resultado, está tarde probaré sus propuestas y veré muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta no se puede optimizar sin reducir el número de registros sumados por fecha, usando paralelismo como expondré al final u otro sistema similar.

El problema que tienes es que estás recorriendo millones de registros para realizar la suma de todos y cada uno de ellos (exceptuando los que tengan `anulado` a 0, que serán pocos), por lo que el tiempo que tarde el servidor en mostrarte los resultados dependerá del hardware disponible.

Por norma general **estarás limitado por la velocidad de un único núcleo de la CPU** porque la consulta se resolverá en una única hebra/proceso por encima de la velocidad de lectura del disco duro o la cantidad de RAM.

En un entorno en el que me he generado 8 millones de registros aleatorios he ejecutado la consulta antes y después de agregar `anulado` como índice:

```
SELECT
  SUM(transaccion)
FROM contabilidad
WHERE
  anulado = 0
```

El tiempo de ejecución de la consulta ha sido, en ambos casos, 32 segundos.

Si hacemos un `DESCRIBE` nos aparece:

```
id select_type table        type possible_keys key     key_len ref   rows    Extra
1  SIMPLE      contabilidad ref  anulado       anulado 1       const 4025130
```

Lo que quiere decir que tiene que recorrer más de 4 millones de registros (campo `rows`). Aproximadamente son unas 126k sumas de registros por segundo.

Tu consulta, sin modificar, en mi entorno tarda 36 segundos. Supone, aproximadamente, un 12% más que hacer la suma de todos los valores sin relacionarlos con la tabla de métodos de pago.

La única forma de mejorar los tiempos de respuesta, y sólo si tu servidor tiene múltiples núcleos, es ejecutar en paralelo las sumas de cada uno de los métodos de pago:

```
# Prueba base:
$ time mysql pruebas -e 'SELECT SUM(transaccion) Total FROM contabilidad WHERE contabilidad.anulado = 0'
+---------------+
| Total         |
+---------------+
| 1147206229.96 |
+---------------+

real    0m32.477s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

# Prueba completa:
$ time mysql pruebas -e "SELECT 
>   formasdepago.nombre as 'Forma de pago', 
>   SUM(transaccion) AS Total 
> FROM contabilidad 
> INNER JOIN formasdepago ON formasdepago.id = contabilidad.formadepago 
> WHERE contabilidad.anulado = 0  
> Group By formadepago"
+---------------+--------------+
| Forma de pago | Total        |
+---------------+--------------+
| VISA          | 382738111.90 |
| PAYPAL        | 382286232.86 |
| METÁLICO      | 382181885.20 |
+---------------+--------------+

real    0m36.378s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

# Paralelismo:
$ time ( for i in 1 2 3 ; do time mysql pruebas -e 'SELECT formadepago, SUM(transaccion) Total FROM contabilidad WHERE contabilidad.anulado = 0 AND formadepago = '$i & done ; for pid in $(jobs -p); do wait $pid; done )
formadepago Total
2   382286232.86
real    0m9.414s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

formadepago Total
1   382738111.90
real    0m9.414s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

formadepago Total
3   382181885.20
real    0m9.415s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

real    0m9.416s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Como puedes ver se ha reducido el tiempo a tan sólo 9 segundos.

En PHP el paralelismo lo podrías obtenerlo usando [`Thread`](http://php.net/class.thread).